# Multiple instances of xConnect collection across different regions

Tags: xconnect

Is it possible to host multiple instances of xConnect collection in different regions? We have 2 CD instances that are hosted in different regions and would like to have a xConnect collection hosted in the same region as CD for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have have multiple instances across multiple regions. But you need to factor in that you can only have 1 xConnect SOLR core and 1 Sitecore Processing Engine service. This means that one xConnect will likely have direct access to SOLR queries and another (remote) will have to talk to SOLR over a WAN.

[image]

Please refer to this scaling doc from Sitecore.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/scale-vertically.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was helpful. I was wondering if the databases (processing pools, messaging, marketingautomation) be hosted in multiple regions to go along with the xConnect collection web app in that region?

Comment: They can be separate, but only one set of databases.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks again!

Comment: Hey @ChrisAuer you say "and 1 processing engine". Which processing are you refering to? Processing server can be scaled https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/processing.html. Indexer can run on azure search too

Comment: I think my words are confusing. The xConnect instance has a Sitecore Processing Engine service that gets installed on the xConnect server. It is different that the Processing role that is in IIS. You can only have one Sitecore Processing Engine instance that processes the new xDB records in the xDB SOLR core.

Comment: @ChrisAuer thanks for this answer. Can you clarify that xConnect service reads from Solr or SQL collection database in order to render a page on CD with personalization? It's got to get the contact profile from somewhere, but is it Solr or the SQL db it reads from? Sitecore docs are very thin on detail.